# passing dropdown seleect option to the url using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, drop-down-menu, combobox

passing dropdown selevect option to the url using javascript and it is working fine but problem is that `<option>Select</option>` also passing to the url now how could i disabled  `<option>Select</option>` while passing the select option values to the url? i want to send only name to the url except `<option>Select</option>`?

```
function getComboC(sel) { 
var name=document.getElementById("name");
var input_val = document.getElementById("name").value;
name.action = "searchexpense.php?name="+input_val+"";
name.submit();


<form name="name" id="name"><select class="select10" 
name="pname" id="name" style="width:150px;"  onChange="getComboC(this)">

<option value="0"><--Select--> </option>

<?php 
$query=mysql_query("SELECT pname from expenses order by id");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$val2=$row['pname'];
?>
<option  value="<?=$val2;?>"  <? if ($_GET['pname']  == $val2)
{ echo "selected='selected'"; }?> >
<?=$row['pname'];?>

</option>

<?php }?>

</select></form>
```

Url While Select `<option>Select</option>` 
**searchexpense.php?pname=0**

Dynamically Option Select 
**searchexpense.php?pname=Test**

Answer (score 0):

you arr using same `id` for multiple elements, like for form and select. **id's must be unique**, so try:

```
<form name="my_frm" id="my_frm">
<select class="select10" name="pname" id="name" style="width:150px;"  onChange="getComboC(this)">
....
```

and js function :

```
function getComboC(sel) { 
  //do not submit if default "select" is selected
  if( sel.value != "0" ) {
    var selected_value = sel.value; //selected dropdown value
    document.my_form.action = "searchexpense.php?name="+selected_value;
    document.my_form.submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: @FarhanAziz you could add a condition if value of selected option is 0, and submit itis not 0, like in my updated answer... did you mean something  like that ..?

Comment: sorry i can't until my reputation more than 15.. if you want i can mark your answer you should give me some reputation...